# All form submitted without trigger js validation on first time load with browser empty cache

Tags: magento2.3, form-validation

I am facing some weird problem on my site.

When i try to reload with empty cache then all the form submitted without triggering js validation.
https://prnt.sc/ov6tk0

after first submit it start triggering validation.

You can check this http://87.117.250.80/~intermedical/ here

On homepage there is contact form near footer.

This is also happen in login/register form

can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: firstly you have a number of issues with your JS mainly caused your owl carousel i would recommend fixing those issues as they could possibly be the reason for the script not being executed first time

Comment: tried removing owl carousel but not worked

Comment: Owl carousel is most likley going to be in your requireJS and initiated within a template file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to upgrade your `jquery Ui library`

Please update it to latest library  you can find it here in magento

> lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js

Replace it with latest or create backup for old file